# Change background opacity only

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and CSS:

```css
.title-wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(53,65,76) 0%, rgba(53,65,76,0) 100%);
  opacity: 0.51;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 12.5px 0 12.5px 12px;
}

.title {
  opacity: 1.0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title-wrapper"><span class="title">Example</span></h1>
```

I want to set the opacity of the title-wrapper background-image to 0.51 but I want to keep the opacity of the text at 1.0. How can I do that?

Right now the text looks really pale. I'm guessing the opacity of the title wrapper is affecting the text.

Comment: Why use opacity in title-wrapper and rgb and rgba? Remove the opacity and use rgba for the gradient. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1kgnmn4r/

Comment: "background image opacity css" on google => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 1):

You can define your background-image in the :before pseudo class

```css
 .title-wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 12.5px 0 12.5px 12px;
}

.title-wrapper:before{
    content:'';
    background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(53,65,76) 0%, rgba(53,65,76,0) 100%);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0.51;
    z-index: -1;
}

.title {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title-wrapper"><span class="title">Example</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use rgba colors  all the way ?

```css
 .title-wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(53,65,76,0.51) 0%, rgba(53,65,76,0) 100%);
    /*opacity: 0.51;*/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 12.5px 0 12.5px 12px;
}

.title {
    opacity: 1.0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
}
 /* DEMO purpose*/
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/city/1);
  background-size:cover
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="title-wrapper"><span class="title">Example</span></h1>
```